# Convert all keys inside [dict] to dict in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

Any elegant way to convert all keys inside dict list to dict? Like this:

```
aa = [
    {"option": "-c","params":4},
    {"option": "-t", "params": 8},
    {"option": "name", "params": "bb"}
]

bb = convert_function(aa)

print(bb)  # will like the following
{
    "-c": 4,
    "-t": 8,
    "name": "bb"
}
```

All the keys in dict in list will always (and only) have keys: "option" and "params"

My solution now is :

```
aa = [
    {"option": "-c","params":4},
    {"option": "-t", "params": 8},
    {"option": "name", "params": "bb"}
]
bb = dict()
for item in aa:
    bb[item['option']] = item['params']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the dictionary follows a format, you can simply:

```
dict(x.values() for x in aa)
```

There is no built-in function that can help you with this. So you can write a custom function as shown in the below **Example**:

```
def convert_function(aa):
    return dict(x.values() for x in aa)

aa = [
    {"option": "-c","params":4},
    {"option": "-t", "params": 8},
    {"option": "name", "params": "bb"}
]

bb = convert_function(aa)
# {'-c': 4, '-t': 8, 'name': 'bb'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [`dictionary comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)  to do this in one line:

```
>>> aa = [{'option': '-c', 'params': 4}, {'option': '-t', 'params': 8}, {'option': 'name', 'params': 'bb'}]
>>> dict((item['option'], item['params']) for item in aa)
{
    '-c': 4,
    '-t': 8,
    'name': 'bb'
}
```

If you want to use a "one-line function" for this you could use a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
>>> bb= lambda aa: dict((item['option'], item['params']) for item in aa)
>>> bb(aa)
{'-c': 4, '-t': 8, 'name': 'bb'}
```

And if you want it even more compact (though I find this a bit less readable), you can do:

```
>>> bb= lambda aa: dict(_.values() for _ in aa)
>>> bb(aa)
{'-c': 4, '-t': 8, 'name': 'bb'}
```